# How to create sequence connected with value from table

Tags: java, postgresql, sequence

I would like to create sequence which will be directly connected with value of field from the table.

Expected table should look like below:

```
id       name     type_id
-------  -------  -------
101        V4       1
201        V2       2
202        V3       2
102        V1       1
203        V6       2
204        V5       2
103        V7       1
```

Name doesn't matter however id should generate like following formula:

```
((type_id * 100) + nextval).
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What is `nextval`? The `type_id` below the current one?

Comment: How to select the type_id?

Comment: Why not create a composite primary key, consisting of `type_id` and `nextval`

Comment: @deHaar Yes, nextval is shortcut of next value. I meant if I multiply same typ_id I would set next possible value.

Comment: Just use the generated number, return a hyphenated value if you must, don't try to be clever with your ids - when 100 values have been added you'll see overlap on all of your types.

Comment: @Lucas what do you mean to use generated hyphenated value

Comment: @Bob I mean concatenating them as a string, so for example a type_id of `1` with an id of `26` could return `1-26` using something like this in your sql `concat(type_id, '-', id)` or you could output them the other way around, it's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do this via stored procedures, otherwise only via logic on the client side (which is rather not what you want). It is rather impossible out of the box...

Comment: I couldn't find solution to do it on database side but I wasn't sure. Thank you!